# Change name of foreign key constraint in One-to-Many unidirectional relation in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm using Hibernate version 5.2.10.

Here is my relation in **Order** entity:

```
@Entity
public class Order {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", length = 22)
  private String id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<OrderLine> lines;

}
```

And in **OrderLine** I have:

```
@Entity
public class OrderLine {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", length = 22)
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false, length = 22)
  private String orderId;

}
```

All is working just fine, but now I want to change the name of the database FK constraint, so:

**Order** (now I use `@JoinColumn` instead of `"mappedBy"`):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FKNAME"))
private List<OrderLine> lines;
```

**OrderLine**:

```
@Column(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false, length = 22)
private String orderId;
```

In this situation I have a problem when deleting an **Order**, because Hibernate sets the `orderId` to **null** before deleting the `Order` and the `OrderLines`, violating the not null orderId constraint.

To avoid this, I have to remove the **nullable = false** (but I do not want!).

Is there a solution? Can I change the name of the database FK constraint while using the `"mappedBy"`?

**EDIT**

As primary key identifier, I use a `UUID` version 4 (random) base64 encoded. After removing the padding chars, it is exactly 22 chars long. The `ID` is generated and assigned at construction time of any entity. But this is not related to my problem.

Comment: `@JoinColumn` annotation on a `@OneToMany` side doesn't make sense. I think your mapping is not correct; if you want you better post both entities; otherwise, difficult to help you..

Comment: Any particular reason why `orderId` is defined as string? As far as I can see it acts as FK in `OrderLine`. How the primary keys look like?

Comment: @ujulu Why does it not make sense? I do not want a JoinTable, because the OrderLine table has the orderId in it.

Comment: @wypieprz see my **EDIT**

Comment: If you want to use `@OneToMany` you must use join table. If you don't want to use join table, you must either navigate from OrderLine to Order (unidirectional) and use `@ManyToOne` in conjunction with `@JoinColumn` annotation, or make the relationship bidirectional: use `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn` on the `Order` attribute in `OrderLine`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing what I wouldn't, I removed the `nullable=false` constraint in `OrderLine.orderId` and I added an assertion into my code to ensure that no one can set `orderId` to null.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach seems to work:

```
@Entity
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", length = 36)
    private String idc;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_NAME"))
    private List<OrderLine> lines;

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class OrderLine {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "ORDERLINE_ID", nullable = false, length = 36)
    private String orderlineId;
    ...
}
```

I have used Hibernate auto-generated UUIDs but idea is same as yours. The database schema is:

```
ORDERS                      ORDERLINE
------------                ----------------
ORDER_ID  PK --+            ORDERLINE_ID  PK
               +--FK_NAME-- ORDER_ID      FK
```

Removing orders works too.

---

UPDATE: a few operations on the entities

```
OrderLine ol1 = new OrderLine();
OrderLine ol2 = new OrderLine();
OrderLine o13 = new OrderLine();
OrderLine ol4 = new OrderLine();
OrderLine ol5 = new OrderLine();
OrderLine ol6 = new OrderLine();
Orders o1 = new Orders(Arrays.asList(ol1));
Orders o2 = new Orders(Arrays.asList(ol2, o13));
Orders o3 = new Orders(Arrays.asList(ol4, ol5, ol6));

em.begin();
em.persist(o1);
em.persist(o2);
em.persist(o3);
em.commit();

em.begin();
Orders o = p.provider().find(Orders.class, id);
em.remove(o);
em.commit();
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the identity of the `OrderLine` entity. Can you insert more than one line per order?

Comment: Yes, I can insert more than one line per order. Actually `OrderLine.orderId` could be misleading a little for you so I have updated it to `OrderLine.orderlineId` plus a few operations on the entities.

Comment: Ok, this is exactly my code. It works because you have omitted the definition of the field `orderId` into the `OrderLine` entity, so it is nullable by default. If you add it (as nullable = false) you cannot delete an Order because hibernate updates it to null before deleting.

Comment: Hmmm, as far as I can see there is a subtle difference - your `OrderLine` has two fields: `id` (PK annotated with @Id) and `orderId`, while mine has only one `orderlineId` (PK annotated with @Id).

Comment: My `id` (in OrderLine) corresponds to your `orderlineId`. My `orderId` (in OrderLine) is the field you omitted (so it is nullable).

Answer (score 0):

In Order, it should be @onetomany and mappedBy orderline_id. In Orderline, you should @manytoone and add @joincolumn with name ID..

Comment: In my object model, the OrderLine entity does NOT know its Order (it has only the orderId). So I do not want the many-to-one relation. Using the mappedBy all works fine, but I'm not able to rename the foreign key constraint.

Comment: I do not want a LOOP between Order and OrderLine (loops are bad things)